# Unable to list data with firebase and angular 6

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Could someone help with this.
I have these data :

```
 "offersByArea" : {
        "-KPCQvj8Pe8Ju5ArbeBS" : {
          "beauty" : {
            "offer5" : true
          },
          "entertainment" : {
            "offer3" : true
          },
          "food" : {
            "offer1" : true,
            "offer2" : true,
            "offer14" : true
          },
          "shopping" : {
            "offer4" : true
          }
        },
        "-KPCRNmbNpoOrSHQlfrG" : {
          "beauty" : {
            "offer6" : true
          },
          "food" : {
            "offer8" : true,

          },
          "offer12" : true,
          "shopping" : {
            "offer9" : true
          }
        }
      }
```

Without Angularfire, how can I list all offers's ref (ex: offer1, offer2) include on a given area (ex -KPCQvj8Pe8Ju5ArbeBS)

I tried :

```
firebase.database().ref().child('offersByArea').child('KPCQvj8Pe8Ju5ArbeBS').child('food').on('value', function(keys) {
          console.log(keys)
          keys.forEach(function(keySnapshot) {
            console.log(keySnapshot)
          });
        })
```

But it returns nothing.

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, although there's probably a better way to read a specific property:

```
function getFood(id) {
  return firebase.database()
    .ref(`/offersByArea/${id}`)
    .once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => Object.keys((snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().food) || {}));
}

getFood('-KPCQvj8Pe8Ju5ArbeBS');
```

Comment: Thanks, but maybe my question was not clear.
I've edited now.

Comment: I've finally made the function.